# After a migration of host, how could I block all old accesses?

Tags: database, admin-panel

I have an access to the admin.

I'm moving the site to another host and I would like to block all old accesses to the to the admin, to db and to all other functionalities.

For the admin, I need to understand if I'm an administrator (I don't believe it). How to remove all administrators and to upgrade my account to administrator?

For the db, changing the host I think others should need access to plesk (that now is only in my hands) to enter db. Isn't it?

What other kind of accesses would you block?